# postgres - An UPDATE is locked by a SELECT on another table

Tags: postgresql, locking

I'm running a light `UPDATE` on table and it's usually done in no time nor locks. When doing multiple `UPDATE`s, I see some cases where the update query is suddenly getting locked. When I check which query blocks it, I see that it's a `SELECT` query on a completely different table.

How can that be?

Comment: A SELECT (that does _not_ include a FOR UPDATE clause) will never block an UPDATE. If you check this using `pg_stat_activity` then the query you see there is the _last_ query that session (=connection) executed. It's not necessarily the query that obtained the lock.

Comment: Thanks! So how can I obtain the query that did obtain the lock? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: You can't.  Once that query is done and another has started, the query text is no longer available.  Unless it got logged for some reason (like `log_statement=all`).  Also, you can write a function which locks anything it wants, and then call that function from a select.